# Can't set ContentView, crashes app

Tags: android, layout, view

I am trying to raw a set my contentView like this:

This is my onCreate method:

```
RelativeLayout mainView;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mainView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    setContentView(mainView);
}
```

the "mainView" is following XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mainView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, when starting the app I get some:

```
02-20 21:35:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(15174): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ochs.androidsnake/com.x.x.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `mainview` is `null` before you set the content. Use this instead.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.<name of your layout file>);
    mainView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call `findViewById()` until after you call `setContentView()`.